# Función .text() es demasiado lenta?

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy tratando de hacer un sencillo juego de 3 en raya y estoy usando jquery para ello. El problema es que para la parte de la máquina estoy usando eventos. Aquí está el código:

```js
let turno=1
$(".tablero").click(function (event) {
    if (turno === 1) {
        let casilla = $(event.target).attr("class");
        console.log("Has pulsado " + casilla);

        if ($("." + casilla).text() === "X") {
            console.log("CASILLA OCUPADA");
        } else {
            //El problema está aqui
            $("." + casilla).text("O");
            console.log("HAS PULSADO PARA COLOCAR LA LETRA O EN "+casilla);
            turno = 0;
            changeTurnEvent(turno);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Espera por favor...");
    }
});

function changeTurnEvent(turnId) {
    let evt = $.Event('changedTurnEvent');
    evt.turn = turnId;

    $(window).trigger(evt);
}

        //Lo que se le pasa a la funcion del evento es un objeto Event, al que se le asigna la variable turn
$(window).on('changedTurnEvent', function (evtParam) {
    console.log("El evtParam pasado es: "+evtParam.turn);
    if(evtParam.turn === 0) {
        console.log("Turno de la maquina");
        /*
        +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
        |                 |                 |                 |
        |        0        |         1       |        2        |
        |                 |                 |                 |
        +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
        |                 |                 |                 |
        |        3        |        4        |         5       |
        |                 |                 |                 |
        +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
        |                 |                 |                 |
        |       6         |         7       |         8       |
        |                 |                 |                 |
        +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+

        */
        let casillas = [];

        //Valoraciones de la maquina para la jugada
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            let casilla =$(".campo"+i).text();
            casillas.push(casilla);
        }
        //Si comienza la partida
        if(casillas[4] === "") {
            $(".campo5").html("X");
            turno = 1;
            return;
        }

        //Si el jugador es el que ha comenzado en el centro
        if(casillas[4] === "O") {
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
            console.log("Numero random: "+random);
        }

    } else {
        console.log("Turno del jugador");
        return;
    }
});
```

```css
.tablero {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
        width: 97px;
        height: 97px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    td:hover {
        background-color: #e2e2e2;
    }
```

```html
<table class="tablero">
        <tr>
            <td class="campo1"></td>
            <td class="campo2"></td>
            <td class="campo3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="campo4"></td>
            <td class="campo5"></td>
            <td class="campo6"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="campo7"></td>
            <td class="campo8"></td>
            <td class="campo9"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Como pueden ver, primero llamo a `$("." + casilla).text("O");`, metodo el cual funciona bien si no ejecuto la línea `changeTurnEvent(turno);`, pero al parecer se ejecuta dicho evento antes y no se como podría evitar eso para que siguiera el orden.

De tal manera que haga lo que haga el jugador la máquina siempre va a colocar la ficha en el centro el primero.

Comment: te dejo este codigo: https://gist.github.com/XaelMaetz/a053450c9545759d437f

Comment: En Javascript el código se ejecuta en el orden en el que lo escribes (llamadas asíncronas aparte), así que el problema tiene que venir de otro lado. De todos modos no necesitas buscar por clase si tienes ya `$(event.target)`, ¿no?

Comment: Lo uso para obtener el nombre de la clase de la casilla que ha clickado @PabloLozano

Comment: He añadido algo de código para poder ejecutar el tuyo, no sé si se aleja mucho de lo que tienes en mente... puedes darle a [edit] y añadir tu HTML si te apetece para dejar claro lo que pasa al ejecutarlo. Seguramente ayudará a encontrar una solución

Comment: Por otro lado no entiendo qué problema tienes, veo que la O se coloca donde haces click

Comment: He actualizado el html con lo que yo tengo y sigue pasando lo mismo :S @PabloLozano